# Upgrading to Android Studio 3.2 is creating Aapt2Exception

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle

I have upgraded to android studio 3.2 and after this studio has started giving the following errors:

```
 error: failed processing manifest.

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

I have tried all solutions provided by others like add `"android.enableAapt2=false"` to Gradle properties or compile, build tools version  & support library version should be the same. Nothing has worked for me so far. Even tried by updating the studio Gradle version

My gradle versions are:

```
compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Does anybody have faced the same issue?`

LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exc
eption: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)


com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$
```

Comment: So did you check log for details?

Comment: These are build failed error logs..i have attached all the logs above

Comment: No more logs? There is no actual reason included in your log, maybe try to compile with debug or stacktrace, also show your top level build.gradle, btw you should upgrade compileSdk and dependencies to latest

Comment: I understand..if you just google AApt2 exception you will find many questions similar to this. None of the solutions worked.

Comment: You already have your first hint in the error message: "failed processing manifest" and "check logs for details". You need to find your build logs. If you can't locate them, go to the Terminal Window in Android Studio and run "gradlew assembleDebug" and post the output.

Comment: Most likely you have an unrecognized tag in your manifest.

Comment: i have started getting AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

Comment: Also error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.